# A POST to iis gets redirected to GET with same url

Tags: angularjs, iis, http-status-code-302

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a call to my Web API (in the same application). In most cases this works fine, but for this one case when I try to POST some data I get a response with status code 302, which redirects me to the same URL but now with GET (which obviously fails since this API only accepts POST).

After much back and forth I ended on a simple example where a POST made with jquery.ajax() gets 200, but the same POST made with angularJS.http() gets 302.

Then I deployed my code to our development server and the result was the exact opposite. The AngulasJS-POST gets 200 but the jQuery-POST gets 302. So I guess there might be an issue in both the call and maybe some IIS settings? I am using IIS 8.5 both locally and on my server. Any thoughts?

Here is the code I used to test:

Web API

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post()
    {
        return "ok from server";
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
    // jQuery - working -> Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/my/api/test",
        data: JSON.stringify({ some: "data" }),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    // Angular - not working -> Response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found (redirect location: /my/api/test)
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/my/api/test",
        data: { some: "data" }
    });
```

Request (in Fiddler):

jQuery call

```
POST http://localhost/my/api/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost/my/test
Accept-Language: nb-NO
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 15
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: FedAuth=77u/PD94bWwg...PjwvU2VjdXJpdHlDb250ZXh0VG9rZW4+; __utma=1.1704028259.1410177772.1421917753.1421924481.153; __utmz=1.1410177772.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASP.NET_SessionId=aig50hiuqza5bjs4nasq1h4q

{"some":"data"}
```

Angular call

```
POST http://localhost/my/api/test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://localhost/my/test
Accept-Language: nb-NO
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 15
DNT: 1
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: __utma=1.1704028259.1410177772.1421917753.1421924481.153; __utmz=1.1410177772.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASP.NET_SessionId=aig50hiuqza5bjs4nasq1h4q

{"some":"data"}
```

Comment: Can you post the full request data for both the Angular and jQuery requests?

Comment: @morrin Full requests from Fiddler added

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `[HttpPost]` attribute to your controller action:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post()
    {
        return "ok from server";
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree it should infer from the naming, but I've had some instances where this hasn't been the case before.

Comment: Interesting, the only difference I see is jQuery including `q=0.01` in the Accept header, and the addition of an `X-Requested-With` header but those shouldn't make a difference. Do post the answer if you find a solution!

Comment: @morring the solution was in the path of the ajax-call (see my answer). In my original code the casing was different on the two calls, but me being smart "obfuscated" the real path when I posted the question so of course no one else could notice ;P I think I will just delete this whole question..

Answer (score 0):

I have found one difference in the request which I suspect can be the answer. The cookie contains a FedAuth-token for authorization (we use WIF) and this is missing in all the failed POSTs (regardles of jQuery or AngularJS). I have not yet figured out why this is sometimes included and sometimes not, but I think this is the what causes the redirect (possibly to our LoginManager, but why it doesn't show on the 302-response I don't know).

Maybe I should post a new question for this, but does anyone have a suggestion to why this would be included on only certain calls?

Comment: I finally figured out that this was indeed the problem. The FedAuth-cookie was not included on certain calls because it was dependent on the path (and not just the domain), and I had written the path with different casing two different places.. And this is of course case sensitive, thank you very much Microsoft!! ;P